# When plotting histograms using the python package bokeh, how can I control the colors used in the plot?

Tags: python, bokeh

Using the code:

```
from bokeh.charts import Histogram, show, output_notebook

p = Histogram(df, values='score', color = 'month',
          title="Histograms for two different months",
          legend='top_right', bins=10)
show(p)
```

I provide a pandas dataframe (df) with a column called `score` and a column called `month`. Histograms are created using `score` grouped by `month` by assigning to the color parameter, `color = 'month'`.

This code succeeds in plotting the two histograms, but assigns default colors of red and green to them. How can I override the default coloring scheme, given that I have already assigned `month` to the `color` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

In the current version (0.11.1) you can pass `palette=['color1', 'color2', ...]` to `Histogram` to assign colors.

I would assume you need at least as many colors in the palette as you have levels of your `color` column (in your case it sounds like two), otherwise things might repeat? (Haven't tested it).

From the [docs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html), colors may be specified as:

> - any of the 147 named CSS colors, e.g 'green', 'indigo'
> - an RGB(A) hex value, e.g., '#FF0000', '#44444444'
> - a 3-tuple of integers (r,g,b) between 0 and 255
> - a 4-tuple of (r,g,b,a) where r, g, b are integers between 0 and 255 and a is a floating point value between 0 and 1

For your specific example, say we wanted the two colors to be blue and orange instead...

```
from bokeh.charts import Histogram, show, output_notebook

p = Histogram(df, values='score', color = 'month',
      title="Histograms for two different months",
      legend='top_right', bins=10, palette=['blue', 'orange'])
show(p)
```